# Office 2019 - installation error message

Tags: microsoft-office

I've tried installing Office 2019 Professional Plus and am getting an error.

[image: Error message displayed]

I have used the Microsoft support and recovery assistant for office 365 to remove any trace of previously installed versions and I have followed the link on the error box and gone through all the steps to remove any parts left behind.

[image: control panel uninstall]

This shows that there are no office based programs, I'm not sure what visual studios is or does and if I should remove it.

[image: system information]

Comment: After uninstalling all prior versions, make sure you reboot the system and then check Task Master to make sure nothing you might have missed is automatically launching.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the machine after uninstalling all the old Office Products?

Secondly, have you used the Office Uninstaller for non 365 versions? Although this could be the same
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8

If all else fails you may be able to use an uninstaller such as Revo Uninstaller to remove anything left over to install the new version.

Comment: I have restarted the machine as it suggested too after uninstalling. I will try the uninstaller you suggest. I also used Bleachbit to remove all redundant artifacts.

Comment: It may be worth using the Office uninstaller more than once, I've had it pick up 2-3 times before. Eventually it fully uninstalled. When restarting the machine did you use Shutdown or Restart? As in Windows 10 they do different things. Office can be sometimes a little annoying.

Just wondering, what is the need to install 2019 64bit? 32bit is a more reliable version of Office and works with more plugins. If you are able to, it would be worth installing the 32bit version.

Comment: I'll try the tool a few more times. I purchased the 64 bit version as my PC is 64bit, was unaware 32bit would be different over than performance.

Comment: Office is a little weird in the respect of 64/32bit. I was unaware you could purchase just one version (32/64bit)? Does the CD Key not work with both?

Comment: I purchased it from amazon uk and it gives me a link to download from. It doesn't ask or tell me it's 64bit other than what it shows in the dialog of the error message.

Comment: I'm not too sure if this will help - https://setup.office.com/

You may well be able to sign into this and put your product key in and downloaded the 32bit version. I have known certain add-ons not to work correctly with 64bit. Did you try the uninstaller a couple of times? I take it that it didn't cooperate

Comment: It's all solved now. I did reply with a post last night with a link of the website that solved it for me but that was on another machine so don't have the link. I used the Deploy tool and edited the configuration.xml file. Thanks all for the advise.

Comment: Brilliant, glad it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

What is your previous Office uninstalled by Microsoft support and recovery assistant for office 365? If Office 2019 won't install after removing all other versions of Office, you can also [manually remove Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manually-uninstall-office-4e2904ea-25c8-4544-99ee-17696bb3027b) and then reinstall Office 2019.

You can also [perform a clean boot in your Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows), then install Office 2019 after you do a clean boot.

To download the 32-bit version of Office 2019, you can also use [the Office deployment tool(ODT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-of-the-office-2016-deployment-tool). For more information, read [Deploy Office 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/deploy).